# Typing Hiragana with combinations on iOS

Tags: discussion

This may be out of place, and it's certainly a beginner's question.

I can find no way to type hiragana with combinations on iOS, using the hiragana keyboard.

An example is kyo きょ I can find no way to type this combination using the hiragana keyboard on iOS.

What is the required combination please?

Comment: You can type small letters by tapping "小"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dim mentions, you need to use 小("small") button *after* you type the "big" kana. So, to type `きょ`:

1. type `き` (flick 'か' left)
2. type `よ` (flick 'や' down)
3. tap `小` which will turn `よ` into `ょ`, giving you `きょ`.

P.S. On non-vowels, `小”°` is also used for adding dakuten (e.g. tap once for `は→ば`) or handakuten(tap twice for `は→ぱ`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 日本語ローマ字 (Romaji) keyboard then the key sequence `kyo` will expand to `きょ`.